# first order linear non-homogenous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following circuit:
[image]

I have solved the equation this far $$ I_C + I_{R1}=I , U=I_{R1}R_1 \implies I_{R1}=\frac{U}{R_1}, Q=CV \implies I_C=C\frac{dU}{dt}, \frac{dU}{dt}=\frac{I_C}{C}=\frac{I-I_{R1}}{C}=\frac{I}{C}-\frac{U}{R_1C}$$
this can be solved as
$$ U_i=\Delta t(\frac{-U_{i-1}}{R_1C}+\frac{I}{C})+U_{i-1}$$
but for first order linear non homogenous we get:
$$ U=A \exp {\frac{-t}{RC}}+IR_1$$
I need the derivation to get this answer instead:
$$U_{i+1}=U_i\exp {\frac{-\Delta t}{RC}} +IR_1*(1-\exp{\frac{-\Delta t}{RC}})$$

I is not constant and can be a function of time

Comment: sorry R1 is R0 and R2 is R1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=I_C + I_{R1}$$
$$ U=I_{R1}R_1 \implies I_{R1}=\frac{U}{R_1}$$
$$Q=CV \implies I_C=C\frac{dU}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dU}{dt}=\frac{I_C}{C}=\frac{I-I_{R1}}{C}=\frac{I}{C}-\frac{U}{R_1C}$$
$$R_1C\frac{dU}{dt}=R_1I-U$$
but we know that the 1st order linear non homogenous solution is:
$$ U=A \exp {\frac{-t}{RC}}+IR_1 $$

In time series analysis we know for first order equations of the form:
$$ \dot x(t)=ax(t)+bu(t) \implies x[k+1]=e^{a\Delta t}x[k]+\frac{1}{a}\left( e^{a \Delta t} -1\right) bu[k]$$
in our differential we have:
$$ a=-\frac{1}{R_1C}$$ $$ bu(t)=\frac{I}{C}$$ $$ \dot x=\frac{dU}{dt}$$
$$ U_{i+1}=e^{-\frac{\Delta t}{R_1C} }U_i-IR_1 \left( e^{-\frac{\Delta t}{R_1C} } -1\right)$$
$$ U_{i+1}=U_i\exp {\frac{-\Delta t}{R_1C}} +IR_1*(1-\exp{\frac{-\Delta t}{R_1C}})$$